# Drowpdown arrow does not show up on IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select, dropdown

I have a normal select dropdown written in plain HTML. I am not using any external library to style it. Its drop-down arrow shows up on chrome, firefox, and other browser. However, It is not showing in Internet Explorer 11. Does anyone know how to manually force the arrow to show up?

```
 <select name="inquiryType" class="dropdown-list" >
                    <option value="${listItem.apicode}">${listItem.title}</option>
 </select>
```

CSS:

```
 .dropdown-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    .dropdown-list {
      width: 100%;
      height: 4.1rem;
      padding: .65rem 1.5rem;
      border-radius: .3rem;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1;
      color: $color-black-mine-shaft;
      background-color: $color-white;
      border: 0.1rem solid $color-gray-nevada;
      outline: none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can't check right now, but if you are not using any external library, it's the browser native appearance, and IE 11 doesn't show a arrow as native.

Comment: ... Could you post an example here, that demostrates the bug happening? Note that you can post embedded html/css/javascript here.

Comment: I edited the question with the HTML and CSS. can you please review.